# iOS - old versions of app getting installed from the App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We just had an app update get approved in the App Store today. However, on some devices, when we download the app, even after completely deleting it first, it is installing the previous version. Is the device somehow remembering the old version? How is this possible? Some devices that weren't used as much for development seem to download the correct version from today.

What could be going on here?

Comment: Did you release the new binary?

Comment: When you say "in some devices"... which devices and what iOS version do they have? is it possible that you are targeting your app to a version higher than the iOS device? and second, are you really sure that it is an older version? do you have any label or new feature that makes you sure that the new version is being installed?

Comment: @Kevin yes, the new binary is released.

Comment: @GonzaloLarralde it is easy to tell which version it is because there are new buttons and features. Some are on 5.1, some are on 6.0.

Comment: And your app is targeted for < 5.1, right? How long has passed since Apple approved your app? is it possible that the old version is still cached in some servers?

Answer (score 3):

Have these devices ever installed your app via TestFlight?  We had this issue and TestFlight was causing a similar issue.  We would try to download the app from the App Store, and an older app version would be installed.  Funny enough, after installing this older app and returning to the App Store, we would be informed that there was an update available for our app, and we would be able to update to the correct version at this point.

Removing TestFlight and its associated profiles didn't seem to help; a factory reset of the phone did the trick.

Comment: I would love to know how you were able to diagnose this problem.  we are seeing the same issue and I would love to be able to confirm TestFlight is causing the problem.

Comment: I have a feeling it had to do with TestFlight as well, but was never able to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: We're seeing this too, but we don't use testflight - although we do distribute enterprised signed versions of the app (with the same app id) via our own internal website. My colleagues think they've seen it when they had the app page in the store open in the app before the upgrade was issued, then went back to it several days later and because the old page was still open there they got the old app.

Comment: I've seen this issue as well.  Based on my experience and reading about other people's observations I think this issue is specific to devices that have had beta versions installed.  It seems to happen when switching from a beta version back to the version delivered through the app store.  2 days after getting the "Ready for For Sale" e-mail from apple the store installed the versions from 2 releases ago.  Force closing and re-opening the app store application gave me the option to update to the latest.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about TestFlight. But, I had this issue when my new version of app gets to "Ready for Sale". Spent long time searching for a solution for this issue.

Surprisingly about an hour it got resolved by itself. So, I advice you to be patient it works by itself after a while.

Answer (score 1):

There's a timing discrepancy between the time your app gets to "Ready for Sale", the time your new keywords (if any) gets indexed by the App Store, and the time the binary downloads actually get updated. From our experience they don't get longer than an hour, but I can imagine that a lot of factors affect this lag.

If it does take inconveniently long then it's probably a good idea to report it to Apple.

Comment: I have experienced the 'old version in app store' issue months after app store approval. I believe this explanation doesn't cover my experience.

Comment: Agreed, we're seeing it in @pretzels1337's conditions too

Comment: I've had it happen pretty consistently and seems to last at least a few days. Could be related to our using enterprise distribution prior to app store approval

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue I upload the new version of the app with the help of iTunesConnect but the app store does not show my new version.
when I upload the app into iTunes I upload the app version 1.06 but due to some error upload is invalid so again I fix the minor error and upload again but this time but not opening again the version (i have already open iTunes so I just upload the new build but not create the new version into iTunes.)

so I click the new version again on the iTunes connect account and set also the same version 1.0.7 and set the same version on the app and change the build number and upload again from Xcode into iTunes and then save and click to submit the after one-day reviewing time my new version uploaded on the app store.
and make sure you are downloading directly from the app store if you are using Apple Store app for downloading then update the apple store app otherwise your app not showing a new version of its show the old version.