# iOS App Store Not Serving Latest Version of My App

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm having a rather strange issue. We pushed out an update (bringing our app to Version 1.0.0) early yesterday to the iOS and Android app stores.

The Android store began working right away, with no issues. It wasn't until this morning that I could see the iOS App Store was updated.

When using a fresh iOS device (one that doesn't even have the old version of the app installed), downloading the app works fine, but opening up the app allows us to see that it's actually the old version (0.9.3), not the new version. Further proof is that upon opening up the app store, it shows that the app needs to be updated. I can click the "Update" button and it will re-download the old version again... and again... and again.

We haven't managed to find an iOS device that works; it appears as though whatever Apple is using to serve the app hasn't yet updated to the latest version (since it's only been maybe 30 or so hours since we initially pushed out the update). However, whatever Apple uses to check for newer versions has been updated, resulting in this problem. In other words, it seems as though the app store prematurely began listing Version 1.0.0, despite the fact that it's not quite ready to start serving it.

Any idea what has caused this to happen? I just can't conclude that it's a bug on Apple's side, as how could they have not noticed this issue in the past.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256527/ready-for-sale-app-cannot-be-found-without-itunes-connect

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700934/ios-old-versions-of-app-getting-installed-from-the-app-store

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think that really addresses this issue -- it looks like the app is displaying correctly in the app store, but not downloading the correct binary.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any ideas what is going on???

Comment: I just spoke to Apple on the phone. They are aware of the issue. I would advise you to contact them and let them know your app name so that they are aware that you are experiencing it to. They told me that it should be resolved within 24 hours.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the information. We have an open support ticket with them, so they are aware as well. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.